# How to send payload to a text area in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where I need to enter payload data like below to a text area ,so how can I achieve that.

> {"u_assettype":"abc","u_assetid":"","u_assetdescription":"ELECTRICITY
>   PREMISE","u_frmp":"Test-FRMP","u_meterprovider":"Provider_Test","u_lifesupportflag":"True","u_sensitiveload":"Test
>   Load","u_mastersubflag":"T","u_hazard":"Asbestos","u_hazardnotes":"Not
>   Applicable", "u_accessinstructions":"TURN RIGHT GO TO END OFF
>   RD.","u_round":"29310","u_sequence":"12","u_meternumbers":"M_12345","u_nmistatus":"EXTINCT","u_street":"FELLOW
>   HILLS ROAD","u_suburb":"MOUNTAIN CREEK","u_state":"NEW SOUTH
>   WALES","u_postcode":"2644","u_region":"North","u_depot":"LEETON","u_premiseid":"BENAMBRA","u_debtornumber":"3803998","u_subnumber":"99-3926","u_feeder":"Not
>   Applicable","u_gislatitude":"10.12345","u_gislongitude":"15.54321","u_offpeakindicator":"CL1","u_lifesupport
>   ":"Yes"}

Answer (score 1):

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("Some Sample Text Here");
```

You can set the textarea's value more quickly using the `executeScript` method on the `JavascriptExecutor` interface. For example, suppose your textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea id='t'></textarea>
```

You can set its value like this:

```
driver.executeScript("var t = document.getElementById('t'); "+
                     "t.value = arguments[0];",
                     data);
```

where data is payload